# What's the scope of a Public Lock - the function, the file or the project?

Tags: concurrency, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script Project (in a Google Site). That project has a File. That file contains functionA and functionB. functionA operates on a set of files and functionB operates on a completely different set of files. To protect from concurrent modifications, each function makes use of the Lock service to get it's own public lock. Each function is triggered to run every 1 minute.

I am finding that it seems FunctionA can't get a lock while FunctionB has a lock.

My question is, is this expected? If so a) what's the documentation reference and b) how do I design my system so that functionA and functionB can in fact run concurrently? Do I need to move the functions up into separate Files or even into different Projects?

My objective for the lock in functionA is to stop multiple concurrent runs of functionA. Similarly with functionB. I DO NOT care if functionA runs concurrently with functionB. In fact, I want them to run concurrently so that things are perceived to work fast from the users' perspective.

I have read [the LockService doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_lockservice#getPublicLock) but it's extremely limited - it just says the scope of a lock is "a section of code" or "a code section".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "per project". Unfortunately you can't have two locks for the same script (unless it's different users and you get a private lock, which is not your case)

a) I'm not the API designer (I'm a Top Contributor), but I'm pretty sure it's by design. They probably limited it this way due to resources limitation.

b) So, you'll have to create a different script/project to have different locks.